# Change negative number to binary in Swift

Tags: swift

I have tried converting Integer value of -1 to binary using

```
String(-1, radix: 2)
```

and it supposed to print out 0b1000 but it printed out -1.
I have tried using another number and looking for another tutorial, but it doesn't specify the negative numbers.
Is there any best practice for this? Thank you.

Comment: `0b1000` is not -1

Comment: you know what I mean, bro. Could you tell me how?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, not at all. Ask more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func printBinary4(x: Int) {
    let numBit = 4

    var i = x
    if i < 0 {
        i = 0b1 << numBit + i
    }

    var str = String(i, radix: 2)
    if str.characters.count < numBit {
        str = String(repeatElement("0", count: numBit - str.characters.count)) + str
    }
    print(str)
}

printBinary4(x: -1)
printBinary4(x: -2)
printBinary4(x: -3)
printBinary4(x: 0)
printBinary4(x: 4)

1111
1110
1101
0000
0100
```